# Filters using ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: java, log4j

Having an issue getting filters to work with Log4j 2 (2.4 and 2.6). Previously I had custom filters using logback and XML configuration like . Decided it would be reasonable to use the ConfigurationBuilder instead.

Just to give a simple example:

```html
   ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder =
    ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

  builder.setConfigurationName("TestLogger");
  
  AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("file", "FILE")   
        .addAttribute("fileName", "C:\\client_test.log").addAttribute("append", false).add(builder.newFilter("LevelRangeFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).
                addAttribute("minLevel", Level.INFO).addAttribute("maxLevel", Level.INFO));   
     
  
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%msg%n%throwable"));
  
  builder.add(appenderBuilder);
  builder.add(builder.newLogger("TestLogger", Level.INFO)
    .add(builder.newAppenderRef("file"))
     .addAttribute("additivity", false));
   
  LoggerContext logctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build()); 
   
  logFile = logctx.getLogger( "TestLogger" );
```

Excuse my ignorance, I am fairly new to the Java config for log4j!

If I initialize the context (just the current class I'm in):

LoggerContext logctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
logFile = logctx.getLogger( "TestLogger" );

and try:

logFile.info("Info level logging");
logFile.error("Error level logging");

I see both of these outputs. I thought with the LevelRangeFilter with a range of INFO->INFO I would only see the info log levels ?

Realistically what I want is to have different appenders based on the log level (as I have with the logback xml configuration).

I've found it difficult to follow the documentation - trying to determine the various plugins and attributes to be used with the various component builders and just the general concepts.

The LevelRangeFilter seemed to fit the bill - where I could add different appenders as newAppenderRef to the build and write them out on to different files based on a tight range.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks!

c

Comment: Solved it. Used this for reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Used this for reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html

I had my mismatch set to NEUTRAL instead of DENY. Putting deny in cut the bad ranges out of the logs. So I was able to split the logs with two appenders using this filter as so:

```
AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilderInfo = builder.newAppender("fileInfo", "FILE")          
.addAttribute("fileName", "C:\\client_info.log").addAttribute("append", false).add(builder.newFilter("LevelRangeFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
.addAttribute("minLevel", Level.INFO).addAttribute("maxLevel", Level.INFO));         

AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilderError = builder.newAppender("fileError", "FILE")            
.addAttribute("fileName", "C:\\client_error.log").addAttribute("append", false).add(builder.newFilter("LevelRangeFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
.addAttribute("minLevel", Level.ERROR).addAttribute("maxLevel", Level.ERROR));

appenderBuilderInfo.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%msg%n%throwable"));
appenderBuilderError.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%msg%n%throwable"));

builder.add(appenderBuilderInfo);
builder.add(appenderBuilderError);
builder.add(builder.newLogger("TestLogger", Level.INFO)
  .add(builder.newAppenderRef("fileInfo"))
    .addAttribute("additivity", false)
  .add(builder.newAppenderRef("fileError"))
    .addAttribute("additivity", false));
```